# Specifying dataset within a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

In some tutorial I'm reading, I see that you can specify the dataset separately from your query, like this:

Dataset field: `http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf`

query:

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
}
```

How do I specify the dataset from within the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `FROM` keyword:

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name
FROM <http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf>
WHERE {
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
}
```

Note: use it after your SELECT statement